# Drop duplicates based on a column, if another column does not contains a certain text in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to drop duplicates based on column id and if it does not contain the word us in either country 1 or country 2. How can I achieve this.

```
ID  country1  country2    status 
1.   us,yt      au,in,sg     monetize
1.   tr,hk      ds,gh        block
2.    ju        te,yu,us     block
2.    ju        te,yu        block


Expected output 
ID  country1.  country2.    status 
1.   us,yt      au,in,sg     monetize
2.    ju        te,yu,us     block
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ChrisLoonam #df = df.query("~(df['country1'].str.contains('US', na=False) | ~(df['country2'].str.contains('US', na=False)").drop_duplicates('id', keep='first').  Do u have a better solution????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["key"]=df["country1"].str.contains("us")| df["country2"].str.contains("us")
df=df.sort_values("key", ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset="ID", keep="first").drop(columns=["key"])
```

Outputs:

```py
   ID country1  country2    status
0  1.    us,yt  au,in,sg  monetize
2  2.       ju  te,yu,us     block
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is dropping duplicates based on column ID

Comment: I tweaked my answer, have a look now